# Flow of Interrupt from lowest level(Hardware) to application

Tags: linux, io, operating-system, kernel

Can anybody explain how interrupt pass from lowest level(Hardware) to application.

So in the below figure I have idea what is happening after processor.
[image]

But I want the process of interrupt from keyboard press to processor what happen in hardware like how it passes scan-code, what is the role of interrupt controller, some register which are set in short how it passes from the below figure ?
[image]

Comment: The first diagram looks wrong for many architectures/OS.  On a busy machine it is more likely that user code gets interrupted.  On an idle machine, it is more likely that a halt instruction gets interrupted, (ie processor is stopped).  'Processor is interrupted and execution enters the kernel code' would be more accurate.

Comment: Also 'return to the kernel code that was interrupted' for same reason as above, plus the interrupt-return may well give execution back to different code, (ie another thread/process), than that which was interrupted.  In your example, a thread waiting for KB input is likely to be interrupt-returned to directly from the kernel after a keypress is handled, and, if the core was not halted, preempting some thread that was running before.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_Interrupt_Controller and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_controller_%28computing%29

The keyboard controller asserts a signal that is routed to the interrupt controller, which in turn asserts a signal that is connected to the processor's interrupt inputs. There is keyboard-specific driver software in the operating system kernel that knows how to access registers in the keyboard controller to obtain the actual scan codes and thence make them available to user-mode applications.

Both the keyboard controller and interrupt controller are typically part of the southbridge chip in your diagram. (In early PCs, all the various functions were implemented as discrete components but many functions are now typically combined into a "super I/O" chip.)